# reactjs proper use of functions and hooks - I get errors

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, event-handling

I finally got a function to compile, but when I call it from within an event handler errors start flying!

The calling code and function is below.
The objective was to get a function to return a 'assettype' as a string and use that String to make a make routing decision.
What am I missing here?
Any chance of some guidance.

Here are the errors:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)dom16.14.0 and react 64.2
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
...

```
GetAssetTypeNameFunction
C:/React-Springboot-CRUD-App/react-frontend/src/Services/GetAssetTypeNameFunction.js:7
  const GetAssetTypeNameFunction = (props) =>{
  const { assettype_assettypeId } = props;
>  const [assetType,setAssetType] = useState()
   
  AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(assettype_assettypeId).then( (res) =>
  setAssetType(res.data));View compiled

ListAssetsComponent.editAssets
C:/React-Springboot-CRUD-App/react-frontend/src/components/ListAssetsComponent.jsx:62
    editAssets(assetsid,assettype_assettypeId){
>       if (GetAssetTypeNameFunction(assettype_assettypeId) === "Tower")
       { 
         this.props.history.push(`/add-assetstower/${assetsid}/${this.props.match.params.sitemasterid}`);
      }
```

...

Button in a Rendered List. onClick calls code that references function 'GetAssetTypeNameFunction'
...

```
<button onClick={ () => this.editAssets(assets.assetsid, assets.assettype_assettypeId)} className="btn btn-info">Update </button>
    
    editAssets(assetsid,assettype_assettypeId){
  if (GetAssetTypeNameFunction(assettype_assettypeId) === "Tower")
  {this.props.history.push(`/add-assetstower${assetsid}/this.props.match.params.sitemasterid`);}
}
```

...

Finally the GetAssetTypeNameFunction function that is called:
...

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import AssetTypeService from './AssetTypeService'

    const GetAssetTypeNameFunction = (props) =>{
  // destructuring 
      const { assettype_assettypeId } = props;
      const [assetType,setAssetType] = useState()
    
    AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(assettype_assettypeId).then( (res) =>
    setAssetType(res.data));

const arrayMap = assetType.map((post)=>{
return(
       <ul> 
           {post.assettypeName}  
        </ul>
);})

    return (
        {arrayMap}
    );
}
export default GetAssetTypeNameFunction;
```

...

I am new to the use of functions. I saw a reference that said: "Do not call in event handlers".

[image: List with Update button that with onClick]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import AssetTypeService from './AssetTypeService'

const GetAssetTypeNameFunction = (props) =>{
  
      const { assettype_assettypeId } = props;
      const [assetType,setAssetType] = useState([])

      useEffect(() => {
        AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(assettype_assettypeId).then( (res) =>
        setAssetType(res.data)).catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });
      }, [])

      return (
        <>
          {
            assetType.length > 0 ? assetType.map((post) => {
              <ul>
                {post.assettypeName}
              </ul>
            })
              :
              null
          }
        </>
      )
    
    
export default GetAssetTypeNameFunction ;
```

Comment: Compiled with warnings.

src\Services\GetAssetTypeNameFunction.js
  Line 15:10:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'assettype_assettypeId'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 20:57:  Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function
                                                array-callback-return

Same Major error upon execution.  Thank you for your interest.

Comment: your AssetTypeService function is not working can you show the code inside it

Comment: I use a Component that has the same code to create the list and it returns correct String.
AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(this.props.datafromparent).then( (res) =>{
            let assettype = res.data;
            this.setState({isLoading:false});
            this.setState({
                assettypeName: assettype.assettypeName,
                assettypeType: assettype.assettypeType
            });
        }); 
It calls Axios:
    getAssetTypeById(assettypeid){
        return axios.get(USER_API_BASE_URL + '/' + assettypeid);
    }
Code works. Image in original post (1 minute)